# Carving runes in a Mesh

Tags: texturing, sculpting

I want to carve runes in a golem that I created using blender but I can't get what I want. I'm trying to use some brushes like "crease" but it has a round aspect...

I would like to get some perfect angles instead of carving something that look like a river. I would like to carve just like I was using a cube to draw those runes.

This is the actual state of the golem.

[image: Golem mesh object view]

Comment: The tool is **Knife Project** and is not the same as Knife as subdividing is recommended. Read about it as people often confuse it with Knife.

Answer (score 0):

One of many ways is to just model your runes, knife project them on the golem and extrude inside as much as you need. And Sculpt mode is meant for characters, with special regard to human face and head. Hence the curves.

Comment: oh yes i forgot to say that because all the rocks are subdivided a lot i can't use the knife tool :/

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option - Try using the **boolean** modifier on your main mesh. Make a rune as another mesh and place it where you want it to go, then use the *difference* option to remove all pieces of the mesh that are touching the rune. This should leave an indentation/carving.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't comment yet, because I only have 31 reputation. That's why I'm answering.

Concerning knife project: maybe you can subdivide once or twice before applying knife project.
After you applied knife project, you can use the bevel tool (not the modifier) by hitting Ctrl + b. After you set the bevel correctly you can just use Ctrl + Numpad- to shrink the selection after which you can just move the runes into the golem.